# How do I write coordinates to a text file after a mouse click? [MATLAB]

Tags: matlab, coordinates, matlab-guide, writetofile

**GOAL**: Write (x,y) coordinates to a textfile (.txt) after my mouse is clicked (using the 'Data Cursor' tool) in Matlab GUIDE.

I am trying to figure out how I can click my mouse, with the Data Cursor tool selected, and output coordinates to a textfile in the format shown below. I want to be able to click the mouse button an unlimited amount of times and write all those coordinates to a file.

**Write to file format**:

point number, x, y

**Steps**:

1. Import Image
2. Click 'Digitize' (Which opens a new text file)
3. Click the image with Data Cursor
4. Show the point clicked on the image with point number
5. Write point number and coordinates to file

***When Digitized is clicked***:

```
 function digitize_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

 datacursormode on

 !notepad.exe &
```

Answer (score 0):

use `dcm_obj = datacursormode();` and `info_struct = getCursorInfo(dcm_obj);`. for example, you can use them in a loop like that:

```
x = 0:0.1:1;
plot(x, x.^2, 'ro');
dcm_obj = datacursormode();
info_struct = [];
while true
    info_struct = getCursorInfo(dcm_obj);
    if ~isempty(info_struct)
        fprintf('you chose point no. %d\n',info_struct.DataIndex);
        fprintf('with coordinates: [x:%1.2f, y:%1.2f]\n\n',info_struct.Position(1),info_struct.Position(2));
        break
    end
    pause(0.05)    
end
```

and you will get:

```
you chose point no. 9
with coordinates: [x:0.80, y:0.64]
```